# PHP/cURL Login Error (File Not Found)

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

I am using PHP and cURL to login through a HTML login form and grab the page that it redirects to. Unfortuntley I get a 'File Not Found'. I am not being logged in correctly, despite giving the right information. I have checked the form layout at lobby.cloudtrax.com to ensure I am posting all the data needed. You can only reach /vouchers/edit_vouchers.php if you are logged in otherwise you get a File Not found.

```
$username = urlencode("xxxxx"); 
$password = urlencode("xxxxx");

$cloudtrax_base = "https://lobby.cloudtrax.com";
$loginurl = "vouchers/edit_vouchers.php";

$postdata = "account=".$username."&password=".$password."&edit=Login";
$cookie = "cloudtrax-cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cloudtrax_base);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);

//Execute the action to login
$postResult = curl_exec($ch);

if($postResult === FALSE) { 
    echo "cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$cloudtrax_base/$loginurl");
$res = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($res);
curl_close($ch);
```

Using HTTP Headers I find that once curl logs in it get redirected to https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/dashboard.php.

But when I log in through the browser using the same user/pass I get redirected to https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/edit_vouchers.php which is what I want to copy

Comment: which url is giving you the error? You're doing TWO curl request there.

Comment: the second URL, I can raw HTML data if I print_r($postResult), but just get File Not found with print_r($res)

Comment: https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/edit_vouchers.php gives `File not found`. If you get an actual page at that URL when logged in then you are not successfully logging in.

Comment: https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/ is also a `File not found` so check that both folder/files exists, if those are the actual URL's.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the page exists but it only allows you to access it if you're logged in. Logging in using cURL isn't working and I can't see why, you can check the login form yourself at lobby.cloudtrax.com

Comment: I once had this experience with a service that was trying to prevent scrapers:

Try adding:

CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0',
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '', //leaving this blank worked

Basically they might be looking for a user agent. To test if they are preventing site scrapers then try logging all the redirects and see whats happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason this doesn't work??

```
<?php
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$name="test";
$voucher="zx9kjspo";
$duration = 4368;
$down = 4.5;
$up = 2;
$maxusers = 3;

$loginurl = "https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/lobby.php";
$voucherurl = "https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/vouchers2.php";

exec("curl -s -L -e https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/lobby.php -c cloudtrax-lobby-cookies.txt -X POST -d 'account=" . urlencode($username) . "&password=" . urlencode($password) ."&edit=Login' $loginurl");

passthru("curl -s -o output.txt -e https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/edit_vouchers.php -c cloudtrax-lobby-cookies.txt -b cloudtrax-lobby-cookies.txt -X POST -d 'voucher_code=" . urlencode($voucher) . "&comment=" . urlencode($name) . "&duration=" . urlencode($duration) . "&max_users=" . urlencode($maxusers) . "&downValue=" . urlencode($down) . "&upValue=" . urlencode($up) . "&valid=Hours+Valid&login=Login+Code&border=0&logo=0&submit=Create+Vouchers' $voucherurl");
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some experience with cloudtrax. Have you got this implementation to work with the new style lobby? As my previous solution now has to be updated.

Comment: Yes.  All you need to do is change the loginurl to:

https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/app/api/lobby_login.php

Comment: you're totally correct! Thank god I thought it was a cookie authentication problem that broke my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are POST'ing to the actual login URL and not relying on a redirect (ie include `lobby.php` in the login URL):

```
$loginUrl = 'https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/lobby.php'; //action from the login form
$loginFields = array('account'=>'account', 'password'=>'pass', 'edit'=>'Login'); //login form field names and values
$voucherUrl = 'https://lobby.cloudtrax.com/vouchers/edit_vouchers.php';

$login = getUrl($loginUrl, $loginFields); //login to the site

$voucherPage = getUrl($voucherUrl); //get the voucher page

function getUrl($url, $postVars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!empty($postVars)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cloudtrax-cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cloudtrax-cookie.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Still the same response. Is there a way to track what pages exactly it's redirecting to?

Comment: Sure via the HTTP headers.

Comment: @c0le2 for some reason cURL gets redirected to vouchers/dashboard.php instead of the intended. Thats where the File Not found comes from